# AWS Public IP Address Not Responding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy a sample application on AWS via this tutorial.
https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux-academy/deploying-a-containerized-flask-application-with-aws-ecs-and-docker/

However, when I go to access the public IP address associated with the network interface, the connection times out.  Everything I have found on similar problems suggests I alter the inbound rules of the security group, where I have added rules to permit all traffic.  Any ideas?[image]

Update:  The problem seems to be specific to my account.  I did the same tutorial with a new AWS account and it worked.  Any ideas for what needs to be modified with my account would still be appreciated.

Comment: Did you do the port mapping correctly ?

Comment: I believe so.   The container definition has a port mapping of host port 80, container port 80, protocol tcp